# How come my html & css looks fine in live server but when I upload it, it looks different?

Tags: html, css

I'm busy with the QR challenge. What means I need to create the same image trying it to be identical. I made this in html and css and to check my work I use a live server in Visual Studio. On the server it looks exactly how I want it to look like. But when I upload it to a site and view it through my browser, it looks different. In my case it has suddenly more white area on the right as you can see of the pictures here below.

[browser wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eufcz.png)

[live server correct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3WhR.png)

On someones advice in de Slack chat I did: reset of the css, changed some units and lay out of my html. She also told me not to style the layout through padding and margin. I also use the browser Microsoft Edge. What could be the problem and how can I solve this?  below here is my code:

---

html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  <title>Frontend Mentor | QR code component</title> 
  <link href="stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <main class="qrbackground">
    <img src="images/image-qr-code.png" alt="QR-code to frontendmentor.io"><br>
      
      <div class="centertext">
         <h3>Improve your front-end skills by building projects </h3>
      </div>

      <div class="centertext">
        <p> Scan the QR code to visit Frontend Mentor and take your coding skill to the next level</p>
      </div>      
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

---

css code

```
/* Box sizing rules */
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Remove default margin */
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
p,
figure,
blockquote,
dl,
dd {
  margin: 0;
}

/* Remove list styles on ul, ol elements with a list role, which suggests default styling will be removed */
ul[role='list'],
ol[role='list'] {
  list-style: none;
}

/* Set core root defaults */
html:focus-within {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* Set core body defaults */
body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
  background-color: #D6E2F0;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* A elements that don't have a class get default styles */
a:not([class]) {
  text-decoration-skip-ink: auto;
}

/* Make images easier to work with */
img,
picture {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 18px;

}

/* Inherit fonts for inputs and buttons */
input,
button,
textarea,
select {
  font: inherit;
}

/* Remove all animations, transitions and smooth scroll for people that prefer not to see them */
@media (prefers-reduced-motion: reduce) {
  html:focus-within {
   scroll-behavior: auto;
  }
  
  *,
  *::before,
  *::after {
    animation-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    animation-iteration-count: 1 !important;
    transition-duration: 0.01ms !important;
    scroll-behavior: auto !important;
  }
}


.qrbackground {
  display: grid;
  justify-content:center;
  background-color:white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
  width: 39rem;
  margin: auto;
}

.centertext {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

h3{
font-size: 2rem;
font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
line-height: normal;
width: 25rem;
}

p {
font-family: 'Outfit', sans-serif;
line-height: normal;
color:  #7B879D;
width: 25rem;
padding-top: 20px;
font-size: larger;
}
```

---

Comment: the only dependecies you are using are that picture and the css file. Since the picture is clearly shown, can you be sure the css was correctly loaded when loading the page from the remote server?

Comment: The issue seems to be related to the width of the img and text inside the <main>.

Comment: @medelito and that picture is expected to be inside a grid layout and centered as per css rules. Since the screenshot shows a totally different condition, it's legit to think the css wasn't correctly loaded

Comment: thank you so much for you response. I already got the fix! @Diego D, you seem to be right. The code actually worked but my cache apparently didn't according to a programmer. When he loaded the link (also different browser so that was ruled out) he got the correct version.

Answer (score 0):

@Diego D is right. In the meantime I figured it out. My css was actually correct but but according to a different programmer the problem was with my caching. He loaded the link to the image and it showed the correct output (he also used a different browser so that was also ruled out).